# Does ServiceBusProcessor use thread pool

Tags: .net, concurrency, azureservicebus

The question is about [ServiceBusProcessor from Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus v7.1.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusprocessor?view=azure-dotnet) used with .NET 5

When I do this

```
var processor = client1.CreateProcessor("queueName", 
    new ServiceBusProcessorOptions { MaxConcurrentCalls = 3 });
processor.ProcessMessageAsync += ProcessMessageAsync;
await processor.StopProcessingAsync();
```

I assume it would all run in 1 thread unless I explicitly create `Task`s in the thread pool in `ProcessMessageAsync`?
(Could run 3 concurrent calls if the other 2 calls get blocked by IO and release the thread)

Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The processor runs a set of background tasks to receive messages, each working independently.  In your example, because `MaxConcurrentCalls` is 3, you'll have 3 tasks running concurrently.

Each task will invoke your `ProcessMessageAsync` handler, which means that your handler is also being executed concurrently.  Unless you're using a shared resource or explicitly synchronizing your handler calls, blocking on one handler invocation will not block the others.

Comment: Thanks! Could you point to where in the code it creates the tasks? Was trying to find tasks but all I found was a semaphore configured based on MaxConcurrentCalls.

Comment: Happy to.   [RunReceiveTaskAsync](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/src/Processor/ServiceBusProcessor.cs#L669) is the core of it for the non-session scenario.

Comment: Thanks! I was expecting to find `new Task().Run()` somewhere. In `RunReceiveTaskAsync()` it retrieves the tasks from `ReceiveAndProcessMessagesAsync()` but then `ReceiveAndProcessMessagesAsync()` -> `ProcessOneMessageWithinScopeAsync ()` -> `ProcessOneMessage()` -> `OnMessageHandler()` and I don't see `Task.Run() ` anywhere along this call stack. What makes it concurrent?

Comment: The tasks are not awaited when `ReceiveAndProcessMessagesAsync` is called.  Each call starts an operation that is, itself, asynchronous.   Those tasks are highly unlikely to complete synchronously due to their structure and dependencies, so each will start and control returns to the caller, `RunReceiveTaskAsync` while the tasks run to completion in the background.  The `_messageHandlerSemaphore` ensures that the maximum concurrent calls value is respected by limiting the number of tasks that can be active at any one time.

Comment: I see, so it's NOT using the thread pool and is not using multiple threads and if I want to I need to use `Task.Run()` in my code in the `ProcessMessageAsync` handler?

Comment: That is not correct.  The tasks are running asynchronous code concurrently.  They're using the thread pool in most cases;  though the runtime has the ultimate say in their scheduling.   The `Task` remarks offer more context.  _([ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=netstandard-2.0))_

Comment: My understanding is that an `async` method has to return a `Task` but it doesn't necessarily mean it will use multiple threads from the thread pool concurrently. For it to use multiple threads concurrently it has to use one of the methods listed in MSDN article you referenced (`Task.Run()`, `Task.Start()`, `TaskFactory.StartNew()`) somewhere in the `async` method or methods it awaits on and I cannot find any of that in this case. Are there other ways for tasks to use the thread pool?

Comment: I think I got it now. Thanks! When the async IO calls used to receive messages complete the framework would schedule the continuations using the thread pool, thus multiple concurrent threads.

Comment: That sounds about right to me.  We could, in theory, kick the tasks off using `Task.Run` but they're heavily network bound and the first action that they take is to await the service operation which won't complete synchronously.